# Load transparent PNG and draw on image

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to load an transparent PNG image. After that I want to put it on another image. The problem is that when I load the PNG it has no transparent part, it is white, and I can't find a solution to fix that.

```
$background = imagecreatefrompng(__DIR__ . "/redblue.png");

$image = imagecreatefrompng(__DIR__ . "/arrow.png");
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255,0,255,127);
imagecolortransparent($image, $color);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);

$final = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($background), imagesy($background) + (imagesy($image) / 2));
$green = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 255, 0);
imagefill($final, 0, 0, $green);

imagecopymerge($final, $background, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($background), imagesy($background), 100);
imagecopymerge($final, $image, 0, imagesy($background) - (imagesy($image) / 2), 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image), 100);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($final);
```

The result looks like this, but the white part (around the arrow, not inside) should be transparent and in this example red and blue:

[image]

Here are the images that I used:

redblue.png [image]

arrow.png: [image: arrow.png]

And where did the pipes came from next to the arrow?